# discord.py: Add all roles from a guild to a user

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to add all roles from a guild to a user. But I don't know how.

My Code right now:

```
@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    roles = get(member.guild.roles)

    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await member.edit(roles=[roles])
        await ctx.send(f'Alle Rollen des Servers {member.mention} hinzugefügt!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Du hast keine Berechtigung!')
```

And I know, I could this do with `add_roles` but I want that all roles of the user get replaced with all guild roles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `add_roles()`, any roles the user already has will just be ignored and all roles that they don't have will be added:

```py
@client.command()
async def addroles(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    for r in ctx.guild.roles:
        try: # it will error if the bot has insufficient perms to give a role
            await ctx.author.add_roles(r)
        except:
            print(f"{r.name} couldn't be given to {member}")
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully gave {member} all the roles I could!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.roles)
- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)